Xorg: "Cannot run in framebuffer mode" infinite loop on boot and how to access a text interface before startx? [AntiX/Debian]
Upon rebooting my laptop today it appears to boot normally and then xorg is started.
This immediately locks it into a loop where this message is displayed indefinitely.


I would add the log file but stack exchange keeps reporting me as spam :(

All the solutions I've come across so far consist of some combination of apt update(sometimes with backports), reinstall nvidia drivers, dist-upgrade to reset version headers, or run configure xorg.
Unfortunately these all require a terminal if I understand correctly, and I've no idea how to get one.
My grub menu has no recovery option, and I'm using a non-systemd Debian;
but from my research, I've tried booting after hitting 'e' in grub, and then with the following parameters appended to the 'linux' line:
1, 3, recovery -- which all do nothing.
single -- which gives me this error:
Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.

See sulogin(8) man page for more details.

Press Enter to continue.

No I haven't messed with fstab, nor any system critical files, as far as I know.
If there's an option to fix the xorg error without accessing a text interface, please let me know.
Although I would also like to know how I'm even supposed to get a text interface, because that seems like a useful skill.
Any help would be deeply appreciated, since I'm at a loss for what to try next.
Thank you,
Note:
The distro I'm using is AntiX23 runit 64bit

Try Ctrl-Alt-F1 (Function key), hit Enter, Ctrl-Alt-F2, hit Enter, ... until you get a login prompt.
